# How to get faster result from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which 6 tables join and all the tables have over 500k rows. When I execute my query in PHP this is taking too long to fetch. Sometimes I get max execute timeout error message.

```
$sql = "SELECT PO.`order_number`,PO.`created_date`,PSA.`first_name`,PSA.`address`,PSA.`city`,PSA.`state`,C.`country`,PSA.`zip`,PSA.`phone_number`,
        POD.`name` AS PNAME,POD.`quantity`,POD.`price`,PO.`shipping_cost`,PO.`discount`,PO.grand_total,POS.`name` AS SNAME,T.order_number AS TORD FROM pg_order PO
        INNER JOIN order_details POD ON PO.id = POD.order_id
        INNER JOIN shipping_address PSA ON PO.id = PSA.order_id 
        INNER JOIN transactions T ON PO.transactions_id = T.id 
        INNER JOIN countries C ON PSA.country = C.code
        INNER JOIN order_status POS ON POD.item_status = POS.order_status_id
        WHERE PO.studio_id=3063";
```

Comment: People outside India won't know what a "lac" is btw. Also, we can't help with your query at all without knowing your table structure and indexes. At the very least, we need a query plan.

Comment: You need to use the MySQL index feature.

Comment: Index tables, show explain().

Comment: Also, is this SQL Server or MySQL?!

Comment: Use EXPLAIN command and add/optimizes indexes.

Comment: There must be one-or more- of the columns you are joining on does not have an index. if you include the EXPLAIN of the query that will help knowing the bottle neck

Answer (score 0):

Use [stored procedure mysql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx) and add indexes in tables.

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure there are indexes for all columns used in join conditions. It'll decrease executing time.
- Be sure there are only required columns specified in SELECT statement. It'll decrease fetching time and network IO.
- Limit count of rows you are getting — use LIMIT statement. It'll decrease both fetching and executing time.